# Can I upgrade RAM with different CAS frequency in my laptop?

Tags: memory, video-editing

I would like to add 16 GB more. Mostly for Video editing on my Asus Laptop. I am not sure if I can go with different CAS latency and frequency. I am noob. Please help me nerds.
current: 8GB
want to upgrade to: 24 GB (8 old + 16 new)
Video editing software : da vinci resolve 16

I have below profile :

[CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrjqN.png)

[main board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEgxF.png)

[memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7JqH.png)

[graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTR2s.png)

Comment: Go to a vendor's site, e.g. Kingston's, for machine-specific info.

Comment: For a laptop, manufacturers often don't provide good information on RAM compatibility (usually they are pretty good about it with Desktop boards), so your best bet is usually to exactly match the voltage and timings of the RAM it shipped with. That said you may or may not be limited by the BIOS so contact support first to see what they have to say. who knows, they might even have an HCL for you to review.

Answer (score 0):

According to Amazon's Question & Answer section for the [ASUS K501UW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DT49XN8), a user was able to upgrade the RAM in this laptop using a Crucial branded module. They provided a [amazon store link to the module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015YPB6HQ) in their anwser. Be sure to double-check the [amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DT49XN8) to check if your product is the same.

> Question:Which upgrades can I do in this laptop ?
>
> I added 16GB of RAM Crucial 16GB Single DDR4 2133 MT/s (PC4-17000)
> SODIMM 260-Pin Memory - CT16G4SFD8213
> [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B015YPB6HQ/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015YPB6HQ)
>
> By Amazon Customer on September 28, 2016
>
> There is an extra ram slot
>
> By Jay on July 5, 2016